# Issue in creating Semgrex patterns with relation names containing ":" colon

Tags: parsing, nlp, constants, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

I am trying to perform Semgrex in https://corenlp.run/ on the below sentence to extract the transition event. Since the dependency relation **"obl:from"** has a colon in it, I get an error. But instead, if I used nsubj, I get the desired result. Can someone tell me how to work around this?

*My text: The automobile shall change states from OFF to ON when the driver is in control.*

```
{} <<nsubj {}
{} <<obl:from  {}
```

[working scenario screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JyVK.png)
[Issue scenario screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3gxP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! Just wrap the expression within `/ /` and it works!
For eg.

```
{} <<  /obl:from/  {}
```